# A handgun vs. Handguns

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, generic

In high school debates, we have resolutions or topics. This month our topic is:

> In the United States, private ownership of **handguns** ought to be banned.

Many debaters will specify a certain type of handgun and only defend that. For example, the private ownership of Glocks ought to be banned. Others will specify a certain type of handgun; a certain group that should not be able to own handguns; or a certain area within the US that should ban handguns.

Would this be grammatically coherent? On previous topics, people have argued that a phrase being a generic bare plural would prohibit specification. Is that the case here or is there some other rule that is being broken?

Here is an example to try to clear up confusion. The affirmative debater will argue that the private ownership of Glocks ought to be banned, and they will also argue that proving this is sufficient to entail the resolution. Some negative debaters will argue that the word "handguns" has no modifier in front of it i.e. some or certain, and thus the affirmative debater has not proven the resolution. Grammatically speaking who is correct?

Comment: I think this is Off Topic proofreading. The entire passage is clumsily phrased anyway; pluralising *specification* won't really improve things. (It probably won't make it any *worse*, but in the circumstances that's hardly surprising.)

Comment: If narrowing is permitted, you could end up with the two teams arguing about completely different things (Team A for brand X, Team B against brand Y), which seems contrary to the essence of debate. Please provide the arguments for narrowing the terms to a specific brand or type.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Although specific to debate, the question is whether a generic noun can be interpreted as a narrowed version of that noun when used in a given genre.

Comment: @FumbleFingers OP is not asking whether the resolution is well-formed but whether it may be understood in a sense which would permit a debater required to defend the resolution to "specify" a narrow sense of *private ownership of handguns*. I think the question is Off Topic because it depends on the rules governing formal debate, not on the rules of English grammar.

Comment: @StoneyB: OP says those debate rules might depend on whether something in the resolution itself is a "generic bare plural", which apparently is only meaningful in contrast to an "existential bare plural" (the former as in ***Dogs** bark*, the latter in *He threw **oranges** at Alice*). I'm gonna guess *the United States* falls into neither category, so the issue is whether it's referring to ***all*** or ***some** handguns*. Which arguably *could* be a question about the "meaning" of a usage, but I think we're perilously close to a "vexatious litigant" situation here.

Comment: **What is your question???**  What is "this" that may or may not be grammatically accurate?  What are you specifying that might violate some grammatical rule??  (I can see why you might get arguments about the wording, since it's incredibly confusing.)

Comment: I'm guessing that is your question. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes it is fixed now @Mari-LouA

Comment: This is slowly becoming more coherent (and more interesting) but still needs a little more clarity. Is you question then "If you use the generic plural 'handguns' in a sentence, does it prevent (or hinder) specification vs using 'a handgun'?" I personally don't think either limit our necessitate specification, but if you added an example of how either direction might be stated, that would help.

Comment: Frankly, you are hopelessly mucked up.  A formal debate topic needs to be MUCH better specified than what you are proposing.  As stated, any "reasonable person" would read it to mean (virtually) all handguns of (virtually) all types should be banned from possession by (virtually) all private citizens.  Any other reading would just provoke useless argumentation that would derail the main debate.  This is not a matter of grammatical correctness (grammar has nothing to do with it), but of the semantics of the sentence, and semantics are highly sensitive to context and individual interpretation.

Comment: I don't see a question of grammar but of logic.  If you want Glock to logically stand in for all handguns, you have to explain why.  I don't say that can't be done, but it is not a question of grammar.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not about grammar but about logic and definitions within a debate.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a topic to be considered by those running the debate series, and is not something that can be decided here.  It may be that there is a tradition of strictly interpreting the statements, or it may be that some sort of "interpretation" is commonly allowed.  The opinions of people here don't really matter, given that the statement can be interpreted several different ways.

In particular, it's unclear whether the statement implies *all* handguns or would accept an interpretation of *some* handguns.

Answer (score 0):

If you say "Handguns should be banned" then you are being absolute. That would be acceptable in law as you would follow with specific exemptions (job types, gun types etc).

If debating the topic and saying that your position is that all handguns should be banned then this is still appropriate. If you are arguing that "some handguns should be banned" then that is also how you should title your argument. From thereon in you would, naturally, explain exemptions.